# Which is the more productive miner output k/sh or G/hs

Tags: mining-profitability

Which would be the most efficient and profitable miner, one at k/hs or g/hs ?

I am seeking to find which "miner" algorithm i.e.  daggerhashimoto blake2s etc would be best to mine with most of the time rather than enabling all

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't really make much sense, I'll explain why:

As a miner, the number of hashes per second you can perform is relevant to the amount of payout you'll receive. More hashes per second for the same mining algorithm means a higher payout, all else equal. The 'k' or 'G' prefix is the shorthand for an exponentiation:

`1 kh/s = 10^3 h/s = 1,000 hashes per second`

`1 Mh/s = 10^6 h/s = 1,000,000 hashes per second`

`1 Gh/s = 10^9 h/s = 1,000,000,000 hashes per second`

`etc.`

With that in mind, the reason I say your question doesn't make sense is that the number of hashes per second is only one part of the equation for determining your mining income. The algorithm that allows your hardware to do more hashes/second is not necessarily the algorithm that will be most profitable to mine. There are many other factors, such as what your share of the network hashrate is, what the price of the coin you are rewarded with is, etc.

---

As a toy example, consider `'mining algorithm A' (maA)`, and `'mining algorithm B' (maB)`. With maA you can only do 1 h/s, but with maB you can do 1 Gh/s, so obviously you can perform *way* more hashes with maB.

However, if the total network hashrate of maA is only 5 h/s, and the total network hashrate of maB is 100 Gh/s, then you will have a much larger share of the hashrate for maA (1/5) than for maB (1/100). Assuming the block reward is equal, it will be more profitable to mine on maA, despite that apparently low hashrate.